# Lower bound of $\left(\int \nabla u_0 \cdot \nabla u \right )^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds

I want to get a estimation like 
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} \nabla u_0\cdot \nabla u\right)^2
\ge C
$$
where $C$ is a positive constant, and $u_0\in C^2(\mathbb R^n), u_0 > 0, |D^\alpha u_0|\le Ce^{-|x|},~~|\alpha|\le 2$. And $u\in  H^1(\mathbb R^n),  \|u\|_{L^2}=1$.

In fact, I think this estimation is wrong, But I am not sure. So, ask here.

Comment: It doesn't seem difficult to construct $u$ from $u_0$ so that $\nabla u_0\cdot \nabla u=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (at least if $n$ is even).

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa  Yes, it is not right, just now I find it.